# why are my double for loops not running correctly?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list of integers T, and each number represents the temperate for that day. I would like to return a list as the output with each index representing how many days I have to wait until there is a warmer day.

So for example:

```
T = [73, 74, 75, 74]
```

Would have output: [1,1,0,0]. Since for '73' I have to wait one day ('74') until there is a warmer day. And same with '74'.
For 75 there is only 74 ahead which is a colder day, so return 0. For the last 74 we return 0 as there are no days ahead and so by default no warmer days.

```
def dailyTemperatures(T):
    output= [0]*len(T)

    for i,t in enumerate(T):
        for j,t in enumerate(T[i+1:],i+1):
            if T[i] <T[j]:
                output[i] = j-i
            else:
                output[i] = 0
    return output

print(dailyTemperatures(T))
```

For the code above, I am getting the output [3,0,0,0], which isn't correct, and I know it is to do with my 'for loops'- any idea where I am going wrong? Thanks

Comment: Add a break statement after `output[i] = j - i`

Comment: @ArnabDe is correct. And for better understanding, add `print(f"Comparing {T[i]} with {T[j]}")` before `if` statement and `print(output)` after `if` statement and you will see what is wrong with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is:

```
T = [73, 74, 75, 74]
def dailytemp(T):
    output= [0]*len(T)
    for i in range(len(T)-1):
        for j in range(i, len(T)):
            if T[i] <T[j]:
                output[i] = j-i
                break
    return output

print(dailytemp(T))
#[1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code for your inputs T = [73, 74, 75, 74]
and also check  T = [73, 74, 75, 73, 72, 70, 80] other example.
The below code works fine

```
def dailyTemperatures(T):
    output = []
    for i in range(len(T)):
        days = 0
        warmer = False
        for j in range(i+1, len(T)):
            if T[j]>T[i]:
                days += 1
                warmer = True
                break
            else:
                days += 1
        if not warmer:
            days=0
        output.append(days)
    return output

T = [73, 74, 75, 73, 72, 70, 80]


print(dailyTemperatures(T))
```